# Template method pattern: changing the algorithm's architecture

Tags: oop, design-patterns, ooad

I'm using template method pattern in my project like following

```cpp
class Template
{
public:
void algorithm();
{
    A();
    B();
}
private:
virtual void A()=0;
virtual void B()=0;
}
```

I have some subclasses implement method *A* & *B* in different ways.
But now I need a new class *Template2* to implement a slightly different algorithm.

```cpp
class Template2
{
public:
void algorithm();
{
    A();
    B();
    C();
}
private:
virtual void A()=0;
virtual void B()=0;
void C()
{
    //some stuff
    A();
    //some stuff
    B();
}
}
```

*C* is identical along all subclasses, so I do not make it virtual.
Right now I create a new inheritance hierarchy based on *Template2*, but this seems stupid because I have to copy and paste every subclasses's code in this new hierarchy.
Is there anyway to do it in a more elegant way?

*EDIT*
Sorry, I did not make my point clear.
Now I have two inheritance hierarchy.
1. An abstract class `Template` and some subclasses `A1,A2,A3,A4...`
2. An abstract class `Template2` and some subclasses `B1,B2,B3,B4...`
This works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a way to somehow merge these two hierarchies because A1 and B1 has the same code except they're derived from Template and Template2 respectively.
Whether the solution is template method pattern is irrelevant for me
Both bcperth and Spotted's answers work for me :)
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Spotted, but have you considered just adding additional algorithms to your `template` class?  Its still Template Pattern with multiple algorithms. You get a fatter class but no code repetition. Below is an illustration.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Template
{
public:
    void algorithm1()
    {
        A();
        B();
    }

    void algorithm2()
    {
        A();
        B();
        C();
    }

private: void C()
    {
    cout << endl << "start C() ";
    A();
    cout << "middle C() ";
    B();
    cout << "end C()" << endl;
    }

private:
    virtual void A() = 0;
    virtual void B() = 0;
};

class real :public Template {

    void A() { cout << "A(1)  "; }
    void B() { cout << "B(1) "; }
};

int main()
{
    real Real;
    cout << "algorithm1" <<endl;
    Real.algorithm1();
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl << "algorithm2 << endl";
    Real.algorithm2();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In fact having a `Template` class as proposed here (with both algorithms inside) may be the best path to follow.

Comment: This is really helpful, I think I'm gonna use it.

Comment: Ok great!  You can close the question by clicking the tick underneath the up-down arrows at top left of my reply. This is not compulsory at all - but is good for the stats :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, forgive my poor C++ syntax.

I suggest that you decouple `A()` and `B()` from `Template` so that you can more easily reuse them in `Template2`

```
class Strategy
{
    public:
    virtual void A()=0;
    virtual void B()=0;
}
```

Then have a common ancestor between `Template` and `Template2`:

```
class AbstractTemplate
{
    public:
    virtual void algorithm()=0;
}
```

And finally implementing `Template` and `Template2` as "final" classes (=no need for subclasses).

```
class Template : AbstractTemplate
{
    public:
    Template(Strategy strategy)
    {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }
    void algorithm()
    {
        strategy.A();
        strategy.B();
    }
    private:
    Strategy strategy;
}

class Template2 : AbstractTemplate
{
    public:
    Template2(Strategy strategy)
    {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }
    void algorithm()
    {
        strategy.A();
        strategy.B();
        C();
    }
    private:
    Strategy strategy;
    void C()
    {
        //some stuff
        strategy.A();
        //some stuff
        strategy.B();
    }
}
```

The overlapping between `Template` and `Template2` is minimal (considering you won't need subclasses, I think it's ok).

Comment: I think you just changed his Template pattern to a Strategy pattern! Not saying that's bad, but OP may be studying Template. One of those XY situations? :-)

Comment: @bcperth First, yes due to the lack of context from OP it may be an XY situation. However, I think my solution adds a value over "just using" the template pattern: it avoids classes proliferation. With just the template you would possibly need N^2 classes (N * Template + N * Template2). With the strategy, the complexity is reduced to N + 2 (N * strategy + 1 * Template + 1 * Template2). But as you said, if OP's intent is to study the template pattern or XY situation, all this is irrelevant and won't help.

Comment: Sorry I did not make my question clear, this is exactly the answer I want, thanks.